# Sum of $n$ products

Tags: number-theory

> Evaluate $$S = \sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)\cdots (k-p),$$ where $n$ and $p$ are positive integers.

I was wondering about this question because doing the positive version of the question, which is

> Evaluate $$S = \sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)\cdots (k+p),$$ where $n$ and $p$ are positive integers.

can be solved the following way while the negative one can't.

We have that $$k(k+1)\cdots (k+p) = (p+1)! \binom{k+p}{p+1} = (p+1)! \left[\binom{k+p+1}{p+2}-\binom{k+p}{p+2} \right]$$ by Pascal's Identity. Therefore the sum telescopes and we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)\cdots (k+p) = (p+1)! \binom{n+p+1}{p+2} = \dfrac{n(n+1)\cdots (n+p+1)}{p+2}.$$

How would we solve the first question then?

Comment: For what it's worth, your first sum vanishes for $n \leq p$.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this work the same? Replacing $k$ by $k-p$,

$$
k(k-1)\cdots (k-p) = (p+1)! \binom{k}{p+1} = (p+1)! \left[\binom{k+1}{p+2}-\binom{k}{p+2} \right].
$$

Comment: What if $k-p < 0$?

Comment: When $k<p$, the LHS and RHS are both $0$.